# PostGIS: Invalid endian flag value encountered

Tags: spring, hibernate, jts

I have a Spring + Hibernate project in which I am trying to save an "post" entity to PostGIS. The objects is made through an http post request and here is the entity definition:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.sidehustle.backend.user.User;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Coordinate;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.GeometryFactory;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.PrecisionModel;
import org.hibernate.annotations.OnDelete;
import org.hibernate.annotations.OnDeleteAction;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.time.LocalDate;

@Entity
public class Post {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "post_sequence",
            sequenceName = "post_sequence",
            allocationSize = 1
    )
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
            generator = "post_sequence"
    )
    private Long id;
    private String header;
    private String description;
    private String jobAddress;
    private double longitude;
    private double latitude;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "geometry(Point,4326)")
    private Point location;

    private String category;
    private int durationMinutes;
    private double moneyOffer;
    private boolean cash;
    private boolean zelle;
    private boolean venmo;
    private boolean cashApp;
    private boolean paypal;
    private boolean otherPaymentMethod;
    private LocalDate datePosted;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    @JoinColumn(name="userId")
    private User user;

    public Post() {
    }

    public Post(@JsonProperty("header") String header,@JsonProperty("description") String description,@JsonProperty("address") String jobAddress,@JsonProperty("longitude") double longitude,@JsonProperty("latitude") double latitude,@JsonProperty("category") String category,@JsonProperty("durationMinutes") int durationMinutes,@JsonProperty("moneyOffer") double moneyOffer,@JsonProperty("cash") boolean cash,@JsonProperty("zelle") boolean zelle,@JsonProperty("venmo") boolean venmo,@JsonProperty("cashApp") boolean cashApp,@JsonProperty("paypal") boolean paypal,@JsonProperty("otherPaymentMethod") boolean otherPaymentMethod,@JsonProperty("datePosted") LocalDate datePosted) {
        this.header = header;
        this.description = description;
        this.jobAddress = jobAddress;
        this.longitude = longitude;
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.category = category;
        this.durationMinutes = durationMinutes;
        this.moneyOffer = moneyOffer;
        this.cash = cash;
        this.zelle = zelle;
        this.venmo = venmo;
        this.cashApp = cashApp;
        this.paypal = paypal;
        this.otherPaymentMethod = otherPaymentMethod;
        this.datePosted = datePosted;
        GeometryFactory factory = new GeometryFactory(new PrecisionModel(), 4326);
        this.location = factory.createPoint(new Coordinate(latitude, longitude));
    }
```

However, when I send the request I keep getting the exception of "org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: Invalid endian flag value encountered.":

```
2023-01-14 21:18:34.928  WARN 18348 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: XX000
2023-01-14 21:18:34.929 ERROR 18348 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: Invalid endian flag value encountered.
2023-01-14 21:18:34.935  INFO 18348 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.h.e.j.b.internal.AbstractBatchImpl     : HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
2023-01-14 21:18:34.966 ERROR 18348 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not execute statement; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement] with root cause

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: Invalid endian flag value encountered.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2675) ~[postgresql-42.3.7.jar:42.3.7]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2365) ~[postgresql-42.3.7.jar:42.3.7]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:355) ~[postgresql-42.3.7.jar:42.3.7]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:490) ~[postgresql-42.3.7.jar:42.3.7]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:408) ~[postgresql-42.3.7.jar:42.3.7]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:167) ~[postgresql-42.3.7.jar:42.3.7]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PgPreparedStatement.java:135) ~[postgresql-42.3.7.jar:42.3.7]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:197) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:46) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3375) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3908) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:107) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.lambda$executeActions$1(ActionQueue.java:478) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:684) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:475) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:344) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:40) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1407) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:489) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3303) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2438) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:449) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:183) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$300(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:40) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:281) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:562) ~[spring-orm-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:743) ~[spring-tx-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:711) ~[spring-tx-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:654) ~[spring-tx-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:407) ~[spring-tx-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:174) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy109.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.sidehustle.backend.post.PostService.addPost(PostService.java:36) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.sidehustle.backend.post.PostController.addPost(PostController.java:21) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1071) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:964) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:696) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:779) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1789) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_292]
```

I have tried many different solutions that I found already, such as changing the dialect property, and this is my application.properties file:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/sidehustle
spring.datasource.username=
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true

server.error.include-message=always
```

Do you have any suggestions?

I have tried different dialects and also changing definition of the column which contains the location/Point object, and nothing seemed to work.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone struggling with this, I had to change from:

```
com.vividsolutions.jts.geom
```

to:

```
org.locationtech.jts.geom
```